# Python Config.cfg - why isnt Python picking though using realpath & __file__?

Tags: python, configuration

I have `imgprocessor.py` where I have included a folder config as in:

[image: here where am using ConfigParser]

When I try to use the file in the context of the folder i.e. if i execute the same from python `imgprocessor.py -f 'nasa.jpg'` etc, the config file resolves. When I install the above package using python setup.py install, then later use a different python program and use it, the file is not being picked. It says cant find config file. I am using the same as per the recommendation of using through `os.realpath` and usage of `__file__`, but still not able to resolve when used as package from different programs but works within the file of program

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot, please copy & paste (or retype) the text of the code. This will greatly help us answer your question.

Comment: github.com/vishnuprasadh/imgprocessor - pls check for the file imgprocessor.py where i have the code of reading config. If you run setup.py and try to run this as a package reference from other module this error happens.

Comment: Please copy and paste the text to the StackOverflow question, rather than link it. SO is trying to build an archive of questions and answers. In the future, the link could go down and future people couldn't see it.